# Get part of substring before character

Tags: javascript, string, react-native, substring, indexof

I have a url, like so:

`https://www.example.com/exampletitle21sep11oct2020/index.html`

The part I need is between the last and second last '/' characters. But I don't need that whole part, I specifically need the last date before the last '/' character. As you can see, there are two dates right next to each other, with no delimiter in between them, making it very hard to use `substring` or `indexOf` methods. What makes it even more difficult, is that the first date only contains the day and month, while the last date contains the whole date.

Is there some way for me to extract the last date before the last '/' character from this url?

Comment: `String.prototype.split()`?

Comment: I can split it easily using the '/' char, but then after I split, how do I get the last date? How do I split between the two dates?

Comment: You would need to do some sort of parsing according to guidelines you've set up. However, it would be better if you could change the path in the backend to ensure there's some sort of separation between start and end date.

Comment: I agree that it would be much better to change the url and add some sort of separation, but the url comes from our client, and they refuse to change it. So now we have to find a dirty way to use the url as is.

Comment: Do you need the second date `11oct2020` from the url?

Comment: Yes @AadilMehraj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Regex you can get second date as follows:

```
const regex = /\/(?:.*?(\d{1,2}\w{3}\d{0,4}))\/.*?$/;

const [, date] = regex.exec("https://www.example.com/exampletitle21sep11oct2020/index.html");
console.log({ date })
```

```js
const regex = /\/(?:.*?(\d{1,2}\w{3}\d{0,4}))\/.*?$/;

const [, date] = regex.exec("https://www.example.com/exampletitle21sep9oct2020/index.html");
console.log({ date });
console.log(regex.exec("https://www.example.com/exampletitle21sep9oct/index.html")[1])
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. But it does crash when I use for example, 9sep9oct2020. I guess that breaks the pattern then. Can I wrap it in a try / catch to prevent that crash?

Comment: Updated the answer to support single digit day as well.

Comment: it seems that sometimes the year (2020) is also missing. How can I support that case as well please?

Comment: I tried with `/\/(?:.*?(\d{1,2}\w{3}\d{0,4}))\/.*?$/`, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Updated the answer, please check the snippet

Answer (score 1):

You could find and parse the path that contains the following pattern:

```
^         Line start
.+        One or more of anything
(\d{2})   2-digit date
(\w{3})   3-letter month (lowercase)
(\d{2})   2-digit date
(\w{3})   3-letter month (lowercase)
(\d{4})   4-digit year
$         Line end
```

### Example

I used [moment](https://momentjs.com/) to handle parsing the dates.

```js
const expression = /^.+(\d{2})(\w{3})(\d{2})(\w{3})(\d{4})$/;
const format = 'DD MMM YYYY';
const toTitleCase = (str) => str.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + str.slice(1);

const parseDates = (path) => {
  const url    = new URL(path),
        tokens = url.pathname.split('/'),
        found  = tokens.find(token => token.match(expression));
  if (!found) return null;
  const [
    , startDate, startMonth, endDate, endMonth, year
  ] = found.match(expression);
  return {
    start : moment(`${startDate} ${toTitleCase(startMonth)} ${year}`, format),
    end   : moment(`${endDate} ${toTitleCase(endMonth)} ${year}`, format)
  };
};

const dates = parseDates('https://www.example.com/exampletitle21sep11oct2020/index.html');

console.log(dates);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Very impressive, thanks. I've been trying to use this, but it gives me an error saying "not implemented". I imported moment, so I know that is not the error... What am I doing wrong do you think?

Comment: @instanceof What's not implemented?

Comment: I'm not sure, that's the only information it gives about the error, apart from the stacktrace.

Comment: @instanceof Just post the first few lines of the stacktrace. It's very important to pay attention to one as a developer.

Comment: Error: not implemented

This error is located at:
    in SpecialsScreen (created by ConnectFunction)
    in ConnectFunction (at SceneView.js:9)
    in SceneView (at StackViewLayout.tsx:900)
    in RCTView (at createAnimatedComponent.js:151)
    in AnimatedComponent (at StackViewCard.tsx:106)...

I'm developing in React Native by the way

Comment: I'm using your function in my SpecialsScreen component.

Comment: So you looks like you have much bigger issues.

Answer (score 1):

Try this Updated

```
const url = "https://www.example.com/exampletitle21sep11oct2020/index.html";
const urlData = url.split('/');
const datePart = urlData[urlData.length-2];
const res = datePart.slice(-9); <-- this will give you "11oct2020" -->
```

Comment: Thanks, but then how do I split between "sep" and "11oct2020"? I need only "11oct2020".

Comment: I have updated my answer. This will give you 11oct2020

Answer (score 1):

All will be much simpler with one regexp expression only:

```
var url = 'https://www.example.com/exampletitle21sep11oct2020/index.html'

var res = url.match( /.*?(\d+[a-z]+\d{4})\/.*?$/i );
// res === [ "https://www.example.com/exampletitle21sep11oct2020/index.html", "11oct2020" ]
var endDate = res[1];
// endDate === "11oct2020"
```

or (but the "exampletitle" must not ends with a digit):

```
var res = url.match( /.*?(\d+[a-z]+)(\d+[a-z]+)(\d{4})\/.*?$/i );
// [ "https://www.example.com/exampletitle21sep11oct2020/index.html", "21sep", "11oct", "2020" ]
```

or:

```
var res = url.match( /.*?(\d+)([a-z]+)(\d+)([a-z]+)(\d{4})\/.*?$/i );
// [ "https://www.example.com/exampletitle21sep11oct2020/index.html", "21", "sep", "11", "oct", "2020" ]
```

But, if you know, that a date is always 2-digits (always "01", and not "1"), the "exampletitle" can be any string:

```
var res = url.match( /.*?(\d{2}[a-z]+\d{4})\/.*?$/i );
var res = url.match( /.*?(\d{2}[a-z]+)(\d+[a-z]+)(\d{4})\/.*?$/i );
var res = url.match( /.*?(\d{2})([a-z]+)(\d+)([a-z]+)(\d{4})\/.*?$/i );
```

Comment: So this will work even if a date of, for example, 9sep9oct2020, or 9sep19oct2020 is used?

Comment: Yes. But in the such case the "exampletitle" substring must not contain a digit at the end. But if the date format 00aaa (2 digits), you better use `url.match( /.*?(\d{2}[a-z]+\d{4})\/.*?$/i )`, it is not limiting the "exampletitle" substring (it can contain digit at its end).

Comment: And don't forget to check the `res` to the `null` value (`match()` returns `null` if no coincidence with a template - i.e. if url have other format). For example: 
`endDate = res ? res[1] : null;` or `endDate = (res||[])[1];`